# Full native android app doesn't generate .apk in eclipse

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, android-ndk-r7

I'm creating a full native app based off this [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) from the android dev site. My project compiles successfully however, after compiling I receive the error "Could not find app_name.apk!" and "Null APK" when building the native application. Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := app_lib
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -landroid -llog -lGLESv2 -lEGL
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

here is my Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

and here is my manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:hasCode="false">
    <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.app_lib"
                android:value="native-activity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'm not sure if my problem is from my code or eclipse not handling the ndk properly. The main.cpp file contains the code from the android dev site. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug, try to remove the android:hasCode="false" from your manifest and add an empty java source folder.